# React Routes and Redux Async data requests

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have been struggling with the standard practice when it comes to data access in react routes.  Here is a basic example:

This is the default store:

```
State: {
  invoiceNumbers: [],
  customers: [],
  invoiceDetails: []
}
```

When I load the Invoice list page I:

1. Load all invoice numbers (ajax request)
2. Load all customers (ajax request)

When I click on an Invoice i use react-route to route to a Invoice/{123} page where I need customers collection and invoice details for specific invoiceId.

Points of confusion:

1.)  When I route to a new page, my store still contains the customer[] and invoicenumber[], but I don't have access to them because routes don't pass store-related props **do they**?  So what I have to do is create a getCustomers action creator that simply returns state for customers.  This doesn't seem right.

2.) I **want** to create a action creator... say loadCustomers()... that will return what is already in the store, but if empty, will make ajax request to load the store with customers. But actionsCreators *don't have access to the existing store*, so how do they know if the store is empty or not?  They can only call reducers, am i correct?  How would I accomplish this?

3.) When I need the details for a Invoice i want to make an ajax request and then store the data in the invoiceDetails[] collection.  When I route to the invoice details page I want just the one invoiceDetail record in that page, but if i navigate to and from different invoice detail pages, I only want to make a ajax request if the data is not already available in that invoiceDetails[] collection.

Questions:
1.) How do I make an action creator, loadCustomers() as described above.

2.) How do I correctly get existing data in the store to a component when i route.

3.) How do I essentially 'cache' retrieved invoiceDetail records in my collection and reuse when necessary?

Thanks for any help you can provide clarifying best practices here.

Comment: did you look in redux's docs ? you need a middleware to do async calls, possible middlewares include : redux-thunk , redux-saga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.) How do I make an action creator, loadCustomers() as described above.

Firstly, it's important to understand that action creators aren't for returning data.  The are used for a creating actions that result in data changes in the store, which in turn result in updates to components.  This is called [Unidirectional Data Flow](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/DataFlow.html) and is a core concept of Redux.  I'm assuming this was just a terminology error and you meant you don't want it to perform the ajax request if the store already has the customer data.

You want to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) (or another async middleware) to achieve this.  You know your store structure and code better than me, but here is an example of how it can be achieved.

```
function loadCustomers() {
    // thunks can delay dispatches and have access to the store's state
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let state = getState()

        // check if customers are loaded
        if (!state.customers) {
            // optional standard action to set a flag somewhere that customers are not ready yet
            dispatch(startLoadingCustomers())

            // load customers 
            fetch("/customers", response => {
                return response.json()
            }).then(data => {
                // dispatch standard action to set customer data in store
                return dispatch(setCustomers(data))
            }).catch(error => {
                // optional standard action to report errors
                return dispatch(setLoadingError(error)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

> 2.) How do I correctly get existing data in the store to a component when i route.

Are your using [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)?  If you wrap your app in a `Provider`, the any `connect`ed component can access any data in the store though a `mapStateToProps` function, so if it's in the store, you don't need to make a seperate request to get it again.

> 3.) How do I essentially 'cache' retrieved invoiceDetail records in my collection and reuse when necessary?

The answer to 1) should cover this case as well.

Comment: 1.) Yes...I am attempting to avoid requesting data if I already have it, and yes I am using redux-thunk so I am 80% there.  Thank you for the code above...that helps me put the get/fetch together.
2.) Yes I am using react-redux.  If the data is already in the store, and I route to a new "page" using connect on the container component, I was expecting that data to be there... but it is not.  If I call an action that simply returns state, the data is there in the store.  But I was expecting mapStateToProps to do that for me.

Comment: Can you post your mapStateToProps function and the component being connected? It sounds like you're trying to do the right thing, but it's isn't quite wired up right.

Comment: I was finally able to finish this up.  I was making some incorrect assumptions, and have refactored some components to eliminate some of the routes.  Good to go now, thanks for your input